# Positioning is wrong on Android when browser is zoomed and scrolled

Tags: jquery, css

I'm not sure whether this is a CSS or a jQuery problem so I tagged both. On Chrome for Android, jQuery UI datepicker and qTip2 both position wrongly (the same way) when the page is zoomed and scrolled. The amount of shifting right/downwards seems to be the same the page is scrolled left/upwards.

Example with qTip:

Normal size, OK:

[image: Normal]

Zoomed, still OK:

[image: Zoomed]

Zoomed and scrolled left and a bit down, tooltip goes right and down:

[image: Scrolled]

My CSS:

```
 body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin : 0 0 0 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

qTip2 positioning instructions:

```
    position: {
        viewport: $(window),
        effect: false,
        adjust: { method: 'shift shift'}
    },
```

Comment: was a solution for this ever found?

Comment: I think I have the same problem and I have been looking for a solution for some time...